# SharePoint 2013 In Site Request Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, office-365

On our SharePoint site we have a form. Users download this form and fill in some blanks with their information then have to externally email it someone in order for it to be approved.

My question is: Is there a way in SharePoint for users to click on a link, be prompted with a form where they can fill in their information, and then have the request saved on the site or sent/emailed to an individual to be reviewed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an InfoPath as the form, create a form and make it as a content type - save it in a form library

then setup an approval workflow for the approval or email notification.

You may refer to this link
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20276.how-to-create-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-using-infopath.aspx